# Runtime resolution of objects to instantiate based on class availability

Tags: php, inheritance, static, dependency-injection

I'm working through a project and would like to refactor certain 
design decisions. Some of the base classes have getInstance() static methods
which return objects that extend from the base class.

Assume the following folder structure and group of library classes:

```
library
   Service.php
   /Service
     CarService.php
     BusService.php
     /BusService
       Long.php
     /CarService.php
       Long.php
```

Intention of Long.php and Long.php is to provide a way to instantiate 
a long version of the Bus or Car, and decide it at run time by passing the type
to the getInstance method. Here's the current code:

```
class CarService {
 public static function getInstance($type) {
   //pseudocode
   $className = "CarService"."_".$type;
   if class_exists($className)
     return new static::className($type);
   else
     return new CarService($type);

 }

 //constructor is not public to prevent user code from
 //creating a base class object

}

class CarService_Long extends CarService {
 ...
}

//to get a 'Long' version instance of CarService, user land code calls
$longCarService = CarService::getInstance('Long');
```

Ideally, I am weeding out all static initializations and I see this pattern
as a blocker. I have started using a dependency injection container to keep
track of objects and providing them as setter and constructor arguments. 
In this case, what would I switch this type of static instance initialization to?

In the refactored code, I would still need to decide which type of object to instantiate
at runtime ?